# Which Media App Supports to Open a Video/Audio file from its Previous Seek?

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation, video, mediaplayer

I was looking for a media player app that would play video/audio from its last seek point when the file is opened, like the one available in Windows VLC Player. I tried it with MK player but it look like that option isn't available. Can someone help me on this, Please ?. like if there is existing free app that has this feature or I should do some config behind to enable this.

Thanks in Advance.

My Device Details

[image]

Comment: Did you try VLC for Mac? That can do it, but it's session-based. It doesn't hard-stamp the file with this data. [Neither does the Windows version, btw.]

Comment: Yup tried it, it didnt work the way it works in windows @Tetsujin

Answer (score 1):

[IINA](https://iina.io/) is a mpv based video player for macOS that keeps track of what it has played and restarts from where you left off.

I have found it to be easier and more reliable than any other video player including VLC.

Comment: Thanks [@mmmm](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/237/mmmmmm), It works as expected! *-*